# Few problems with social game

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, transactions

I'm developing one social game which is similar to friends for sale game.

In the game user buys and sells friends.
Buyer of the user becomes owner of that user.

I developed logic and it works perfect as per calculation.

But when we have many number of users there is problem with this action of buy button.

E.g. 5 users are on same profile i.e. UserXYZ.  Now 2 of them clicks on buy button at the same time, same second.

Amount of cash is being loose from both the accounts but only one becomes owner.

I want to stop this cash losing problem.

This problem occurs because script executes at the same time for both the users but only one of them becomes owner.

I have no idea how to stop this over sale clicks. Website is in PHP/MySQL.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Not really a javascript or AJAX question - this is more about managing transactions on the server.

Comment: Not specific enough. Please post your code so that we can help solve your problem.

Comment: lock your table, also logic is probably wrong since that happens...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In PHP MySQL we have table level locks.  If user1 and user2 are on user3's page, lock will be occupy by one user but problem is that at the same time user4 and user5 will be on user6's page but none of them can access lock because this is table level lock and lock is occupied by user1/user2.  This will create deadlock I think.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing any of your code, i can't really give a code answer,  but, in theory i would fix this like so:

1. when your sending your ajax "buy friend"  request,  send the current owner id along with it.
2. In your php, check if the friend that is getting bought has the same owner, if it does, do the sale, if not, reply a friendly message saying "sorry, someone else bought them"

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  On ajax call I fetch last owner.  E.g. User121 is last owner of UserXYZ.  But problem is that two users are clicking at the same time on the same second so ajax is being called from both the buyers at the same second and of course owner is not changed yet.  Once any of them gets that user, he/she will be new owner.  But both users looses cash and only one becomes owner.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subtracting the money from the front-end, subtract the money from the backend **after** the user has been successfully added to that owner.  That way you avoid the problem.  Make sure you pass the ownerid to the backend, which you should be doing already.